# Joomla 3.x extension development tutorial for a beginner developer

Tags: component, development, cms, module, extensions

I worked extensively in Joomla 1.0.15 version and developed multiple extensions. Also, I continued my developed in Joomla 1.5.x
But, my developed discontinued after this release. Now, I want to start my development again with Joomla 3.x. I can see that Joomla has made multiple enhancement like MVC, responsive template, workflow and many more.

- Can someone provide me the easiest roadmap and tutorials links for
  this?
- What is the new workflow now ?
- What is the new MVC architecture ?

Comment: May I know why my question has been downvoted?

Comment: It was me that downvoted the question. The reason being is because it struck me as the sort of question that would lead to link only answers, which as a matter of fact has occurred (apart from @Anibal), which can simply be found by a small Google search. As much as I am all for people getting help as I understand things can be confusing, I think it's always good for the user to do some research. Remember, as all devs say, Google is your best friend :)

Comment: @Lodder: No issue. I also agree with you but reason behind posting my question on this dedicated Joomla forum is to get a consolidated and authentic list of Joomla development tutorials.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I will provide the list of my bookmarked links and a list with links for Joomla Development Books, with various resources all around Joomla Development. I hope they will be useful for anyone interested:

### Joomla Beginner Users start here:

- **[Joomla Beginner Tutorials - How to start with Joomla?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16529/joomla-beginner-tutorials-how-to-start-with-joomla)**
- [**Glossary**](https://docs.joomla.org/Glossary) - It's a good idea to get familiar with Joomla Glossary first.

#### 2020 Update:

- I just found this website and YouTube channel, which contains rich content and many video tutorials around Joomla. It worths listing it here.

  - https://www.learnjoomlafast.com/
  - https://www.youtube.com/c/MathewTamin

---

### JSE Useful Links:

- **[What tools can I use to help assist me with Joomla development?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/12143/what-tools-can-i-use-to-help-assist-me-with-joomla-development)**
- [**Joomla Application Execution Flow**](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17108/what-is-the-joomla-execution-flow-after-a-request-reach-to-index-php-till-the-f/17109#17109)

---

### Joomla Development Online Resources:

- [**Absolute Basics of How a Component Functions**](http://docs.joomla.org/Absolute_Basics_of_How_a_Component_Functions)
- [**Component Program Flow**](http://docs.joomla.org/Component_Program_Flow)
- [**Developing a MVC Component**](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_MVC_Component)
- [**Joomla! 3 extension development tips and resources**](http://www.chillcreations.com/news/joomla/559-joomla-3-extension-development-tips-resources)
- [**Developer Manual**](http://developer.joomla.org/manual/index.html)
- [**Getting Started with Composer and Joomla!**](http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-aug-2013/item/1450-getting-started-with-composer-and-joomla)
- [**Lendr - Joomla Component Tutorial**](http://lendr.websparkinc.com/)
- [**Joomla 3.2 Tutorials**](http://www.joomlatutorials.com/joomla-tutorials/joomla-3-2-tutorials)
- [**Joomla! API**](http://api.joomla.org/)

---

### Joomla & PHP Development Books:

- [**Joomla! Development Guide (FREE - PDF Download)**](http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-jan-2012/item/655-Download-the-free-Joomla-Development-Guide)
- [**Joomla! Programming**](http://joomlaprogrammingbook.com)
- [**Learning Joomla! 3 Extension Development**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1782168370)
- [**Programming Joomla Plugins**](https://www.yireo.com/books/programming-joomla-plugins-book)
- [**Advanced Joomla!**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143021628X)
- [**PHP Objects, Patterns and Practice**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430260319)

---

### Recommended Udemy Video Tutorials

- [**Joomla! Extension Development Workflow with Vagrant**](https://www.udemy.com/joomla-extension-development-with-vagrant/)
  <sub>*This one made by our JSE moderator Valentin Despa</sub>
- [**Learning Joomla! 3 Extension Development - (paid)**](https://www.udemy.com/learning-joomla-3-extension-development/)

---

### Other Useful Links

- [**Joomla Documentation Resources: Development**](https://docs.joomla.org/Category:Development)
- [**Joomla Developers Portal**](https://docs.joomla.org/Developers)
- [**Joomla Class Hierarchy Graph**](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/graph_class.html)

Comment: VERY useful @FFrewin, may I share this in JoomlaLondon Google+ community?

Comment: @BodgeIT : That is definitely ok mate.

Answer (score 8):

I can recommend the official doc page. There is a section for developers which includes also tutorials. http://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Developers

David Hurley is currently doing a series of short videos which explain how to develop various things. http://dbhurley.com/jd101-joomla-development-tutorial-series/

The API page is a good ressource as well. http://api.joomla.org/

That should help get you started.

Answer (score 7):

Previous answers are comprehensive about Joomla Core MVC. As an alternative MVC for Joomla, **FOF**

https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/fof/introducing-fof.html#what-is-fof

https://github.com/akeeba/fof

**What is FOF**

FOF (Framework on Framework) is a rapid application development framework for Joomla!. Unlike other frameworks it is not standalone. It extends the Joomla! Platform instead of replacing it, featuring its own forked and extended version of the MVC classes, keeping a strong semblance to the existing Joomla! MVC API. This means that you don't have to relearn writing Joomla! extensions. Instead, you can start being productive from the first day you're using it. Our goal is to always support the officially supported LTS versions of Joomla! and not break backwards compatibility without a clear deprecation and migration path.

FOF is compatible with the database technologies used by Joomla! itself: MySQL, SQL Server (and Windows Azure SQL), PostgreSQL. In most cases you can write a component in one database server technology and have it run on the other database server technologies with minimal or no effort.

FOF is currently used by free and commercial components for Joomla! by an increasing number of developers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a sample mvc component developed in joomla3 you can view [this link](http://a2znotes.blogspot.in/2015/02/creating-joomla-mvc-component.html) having several samples component with admin and site, with acl or without acl, with all form field types.