# Joomla 3.4.2 - add more menu type in same component

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, joomla-3.3.x, joomla-3.4

I had followed this basic [tutorial](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_a_menu_type_to_the_site_part) and successful created new menu type name "hello world" with 2 views inside "tmpl" folder name "default.php" & "other.php"

[image: Menu].

[image: Problem]

The problem here is, I wanted to create 2 different views with different content inside each view. But both of 2 files "other.php & default.php" are point to com_helloworld/helloworld.php with same content in helloworld.php file. I tried to search for solution several hours but unable to find a solution for this issue. Please advise how to point out the "other.php" file in tmpl folder to different file instead of current "helloworld.php" file :(

Comment: Hello SonDang, I feel your question is too broad and it will be hard to get a thorough answer. I would suggest to read more about developing components and the MVC pattern. You can find more resources here: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3579/joomla-3-x-extension-development-tutorial-for-a-beginner-developer. If you are interested, there are a few good books about creating Joomla extensions. Just search for Joomla development books.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion FFrewin, I will check in the resources in share for solution :(

Answer (score 2):

You created two *layouts* (stored in `views/helloworld/tmpl`). 
What you want to do is create a new *view*, i.e. `views/other/`

In the `view.html.php` file therein you can invoke the same or a different model to get the data you want. Look at the code of some simple components like `com_users` to get a feel of how it's done, or read the docs.