# How to modify Joomla template to make my own personal site?

Tags: templates, gavick

I've downloaded and installed the LAMP stack, and the template meetGavern.
I've got everything up and running, I ran the install procedure and now I can load up the meetGavern template site.

Now, I wish to get started morphing this template into my own personal website. I have no idea where to begin, this is my first time using Joomla.

I understand this is a broad question but oddly my searches are not giving me any direction, every resource I find seems to assume in-depth knowledge of Joomla.

Comment: [**Joomla Beginner Tutorials/Learning Resources**](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16529/joomla-beginner-tutorials-how-to-start-with-joomla?lq=1)

Comment: [**Joomla Developer Tutorials/Learning Resources**](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3579/joomla-3-x-extension-development-tutorial-for-a-beginner-developer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the requirements for your "*own personal website*", What exactly
 you need integrate into the template?

- Find more information about Gavern Framework here:
  https://www.gavick.com/documentation/joomla/gavern-framework
- Find more information for Joomla! Templates here:
  https://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Template_Development

Also you have this useful guide: https://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Beginners

Comment: I don't think it's important what specific type of website I want to design, those details are out of scope here. I just want to know how I can get started modifying the template, even if its just removing / adding some blocks to get the hang of it.