# Joomla Beginner Tutorials - How to start with Joomla?

Tags: joomla-3.x, installation, administration, features

A friend told me to use this Joomla to set up my own website. Truth is I have no idea how to start with it. I have some html, css, php knowledge but never had to use a CMS before and specifically Joomla.

Searching around, I usually find resources that seem more advanced for me to get me started.

Can someone point me to resources about the basics of using Joomla?

Comment: This Q/A is a response to this type of questions: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16524/how-to-modify-joomla-template-to-make-my-own-personal-site

Comment: For more advanced/development resources: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3579/joomla-3-x-extension-development-tutorial-for-a-beginner-developer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some helpful resources for beginners and Joomla newbies.

(for developers tutorials go: [Joomla 3.x extension development tutorial for a beginner developer](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3579/joomla-3-x-extension-development-tutorial-for-a-beginner-developer))

## Joomla Docs

- [**Getting started with Joomla**](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Getting_Started_with_Joomla!)
- [**Joomla Beginners Tutorials**](https://docs.joomla.org/Tutorials:Beginners)
- [**Joomla Portal: Beginners**](https://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Beginners)
- [**Joomla Portal: Administrator Manual**](https://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Administrators)
- [**Joomla Terminology**](https://docs.joomla.org/Terminology)
- [**Joomla Glossary**](https://docs.joomla.org/Glossary)
- [**Some Basic Video Tutorials on Joomla.org**](https://community.joomla.org/joomla-training.html)

## 3rd Party

- [**Siteground Joomla Tutorials**](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/joomla/)
- [**Joomlatutorials.com**](https://www.joomlatutorials.com)
- [**Udemy Joomla Tutorials**](https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?q=joomla&src=ukw&lang=en)
- [**Lynda.com Joomla Tutorials**](https://www.lynda.com/Joomla-training-tutorials/245-0.html)

#### 2020 Update:

- I just found this website and YouTube channel, which contains rich content and many video tutorials around Joomla. It worths listing it here.

  - https://www.learnjoomlafast.com/
  - https://www.youtube.com/c/MathewTamin

## Joomla Learning/Support Sites

- [**Ostraining.com**](https://www.ostraining.com)
- [**JoomlaShack**](https://www.joomlashack.com/university)

## Books

- [**Joomla Explained**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321703782)
- [**The official Joomla Book**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321704215)
- [**Joomla! 3 Beginner's Guide**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1782164340)
- [**Joomla for dummies**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470599022)
- [**Joomla Bible**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118474910)
- [**Joomla Programming**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013278081X)
- [**Advanced Joomla!**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143021628X)

Answer (score 2):

To complement, there are two areas in which at some point will have to review due to the importance with the creation and administration of sites:

- [Joomla Security Checklist](https://docs.joomla.org/Security_Checklist)
- [Search Engine Optimisation](https://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Search_Engine_Optimisation)

Comment: just noticed your attribution - these are good additions