# How to show previous/next buttons in my articles?

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, articles, com-content, pagination

I'm using helix3. my website is 1PSD.net. how to put a button "next" in bottom my pages?like this picture? [image]
[image]
I mean, not button "READ MORE". I want multiple pages similar the left post "Beginners" and right post "Professionals" in home page. thank you very much.

#### Update

When you click on "professionals" in home. You enter this page: 1psd.net/index.php/using-joomla/extensions/components/… bottom this page is "prev" and "next". but when you click on "upgraders" in home."prev" and "next" does not exist. How to put "prev" and "next" for "upgraders"?

Comment: Hi, is it possible to explain a bit clearer what you want to do? What do you mean with multi-page, what is multiple pages similar to the left post and right ... ?

Comment: when you click on "professionals" in home. You enter this page: http://1psd.net/index.php/using-joomla/extensions/components/content-component/article-category-list/35-professionals bottom this page is "prev" and "next". but when you click on "upgraders" in home."prev" and "next" does not exist. How to put "prev" and "next" for "upgraders"? thank you

Comment: I see next/prev buttons on upgraders page: http://1psd.net/index.php/using-joomla/extensions/components/content-component/article-category-list/50-upgraders. However since this is just the quickstart demo site and from your question it looks like you are totally new in Joomla, I would suggest to read the documentation of Joomla and template, and also follow some Joomla beginner tutorials to start learning how Joomla works.

Comment: Follow the links posted on this Q/A https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16529/joomla-beginner-tutorials-how-to-start-with-joomla

Answer (score 3):

To display Next / Previous buttons at the bottom of articles pages, then first of all the content pagination plugin should be enabled.

Then for each of the articles, the corresponding value of `show pagination`, should be set to Show (Yes). This can be set globally in the global `com_content` configuration (options), or at the menu item that is responsible for a particular article view (e.g. a blog category layout menu item can control the display for these articles), or on per article level (article options).

Do note, that the pagination will occur only among articles of the same category.

Comment: Thank you very much. by default is 2 page for previous/next. How do we increase the number of pages?