# Solidres Data Report for Joomla Admin

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, php7

I am pretty new to Joomla & PHP so this is a broad question.

My client is looking for some custom reports for Admin login on data prepared by [Solidres](https://www.solidres.com/) as that Solidres doesn't have those reports.

Being pretty new, I am not sure as how to proceed & start development? I am not able to find helpful tutorials on the topic.

Report format has to be - PDF, CSV and ODS

Report can only be viewed and printed & UI should give option to send report file in email too.

There is a second category of report that needs to be generated automatically via cron job that user can view or download.

Any link to tutorials , videos , books and guidelines are welcome.

I am just looking for high level steps and can work my way out, looking for just a bit of guidance.

Comment: Wow, that is a tremendously broad question.  The mission of this community is never just to support a single user -- it is to answer isolated questions in a way that will benefit countless researchers in the future.  Even if a volunteer was able offer fantastic advice, it would be largely subjective/opinion-based and ride on many assumption given your brief.  There actually might be 10 or more questions in this question.  My advice is to write out all of the objectives, then brainstorm ways to achieve them based on your currently available data.  When you get stuck with a process, let us know.

Comment: Honestly, we want to help you -- that's what this community is for.  It is comforting to know that you don't have to go it alone.  I'm just not sure your question is yet ready for this Q & A.

Comment: @mickmackusa : Thanks for the comments and at the beginning I knew that my question is broad & I didn't ask it forum at first attempt. I have been browsing from last three days but unfortunately, not able to find anything to the point. My topic would be - **How do we present summarized reports to admin user in Joomla** ? Any approach will get me started provided I get some public links. Anyway, I am looking for physical help at my office. I didn't faced such issues in my Java career of 13 years :)

Comment: What I find on google are usually ready made paid plugins and that is not what I am looking for.TJ Reports is something seems relevant to my need but I am not very sure as how to use it.

Comment: Linking a [related question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16529/joomla-beginner-tutorials-how-to-start-with-joomla/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically your question is: **how to become a Joomla plugin/component developer?** - since you need a specific plugin/component which extends another Joomla component.

Since you have a quite nice background (13 years) in Java programming, now you have to learn of course PHP (which you can do quite easily), then you have to deeply study the Joomla CMS and maybe the Joomla Framework. From my experience, I can tell you that it's a great adventure, a lot of fun, but at the same time it's a huge headache too. I love PHP and Joomla but let's be honest. :)

**My suggestions on how to start this:**

1. Study and do the steps of this article series (if you already have acceptable PHP knowledge): 
   https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component

   (if you get stuck or cannot grasp the concept of what's going on then shift to the next steps and get back to this first 'course' later).
2. If you want to improve your PHP knowledge then get a good book (or course) on PHP.
3. Buy or get a book specifically on **'Joomla programming'** (even if it is a bit outdated).
4. Additionally it is very much recommended to also study the Joomla plugin development (it can be even before studying component development).
   My favorite book about Joomla Plugins is written by Jisse Reitsma (I think the best book written about the subject of Jooomla - 2014): https://www.yireo.com/books/programming-joomla-plugins-book/downloads

(if the above process takes too long, then it is better to hire a Joomla developer to do the required job.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think , I need to develop a plugin on top of [this](https://github.com/techjoomla/com_tjreports). There is a sample code there, will try to get it working.

Comment: Yes, I see that you would like to have a plugin or component which can use the classes/functions of TJReport plugin. That can be also an option for you. However when you will get to the point where you will see the concepts of a Joomla plugin or component more clearly (few weeks later), then you will be able to build one Joomla component without using TJReport. :)