# Creating a module/component that can be attached to a menu item with the Menu Item Type selector

Tags: component, menu-item, custom-component

I can create a component/module to fill main page area.  I can even embed that in an article, and have that article attached to a Menu Item with the Menu Manager.

However, I want my component to appear as an select-able option in the Menu Item Type dialog (Menus: Edit Item, then click on SELECT in the Menu Item Type line).

Is there an XML entry or some other way of flagging my component so that it will appear in this dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have created your models/views, you need the respective .xml file for each of your view's templates that you want to add a menu item.

See for example the `com_content` component.

Go into: `components/com_content/views/article/tmp`

There you will see `default.php` which is the template file and `default.xml` which is the xml that defines the menu item for that template/layout.

#### Read also:

- **[Joomla 3.x extension development tutorial for a beginner developer](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3579/joomla-3-x-extension-development-tutorial-for-a-beginner-developer)**
- [**Developing an MVC Component/Adding a menu type to the site part**](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_a_menu_type_to_the_site_part)